# How to deploy a Python Telegram bot on Azure?

Tags: python, azure, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have Python-based telegram bot code which I want to deploy in azure.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("abc_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)

# Define a function to handle the /start command
@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):
    # Send "Hello" as a response to the /start command
    message.reply_text("Hello!")

# Run the bot
app.run()
```

I already have tried multiple things but couldn't deploy it, please guide me through right direction where I can deploy Python telegram bot code in azure. I have used the pyrogram library to build my bot.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple Telegram chat bot using your python code.

- Set **Bot Token** as **environment variable**:

```
set BOT_TOKEN= <bot_token>
```

```py
import os

from pyrogram import Client, filters

BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
app = Client("kpvrhello_bot", api_id=277XXXX18, api_hash="2d85ec95c014fXXXXXXe6269d", bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):

    message.reply_text("Hello Pravallika, Welcome!!!")

app.run()
```

- **Deployed to Azure using Visual Studio Code:**

[image]

- Go to Environment variables (or Configuration=>General Settings), add new application setting `BOT_TOKEN`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the help, just wanted to ask did you also created a requirements.txt file and can we deploy it using our free subscription.

Comment: Yes, I have created it manually and yes you can deploy with free subscription as well.

Comment: i followed the steps created web app. added bot token in application setting, the deployment went successful but the bot didn't respond.

Comment: i did it, it got deployed successfully, the error was in the environment variable and finally i deployed the bot. thank you again for the help !

Comment: after a certain period of time mostly 250 seconds the bot stops working below is the stream log.
2024-02-21T05:53:17.370Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_43bb3257 for site mainbot1 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 249.5443449 sec

2024-02-21T05:53:17.382Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_43bb3257 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2024-02-21T05:53:17.401Z INFO - Stopping site mainbot1 because it failed during startup.