# Container Fails to Start After 250 Seconds: How to Troubleshoot and Resolve HTTP Ping Timeout on Port 8000? deploying in Microsoft Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, pyrogram

When deploying my Telegram bot code on Azure App Service, the deployment is successful, and the bot starts functioning properly. However, after approximately 250 seconds, the bot abruptly stops working. Below is the relevant code snippet and the error log from the Azure App Service log stream:

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("abc_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)

#Define a function to handle the /start command
@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):
    #Send "Hello" as a response to the /start command
    message.reply_text("Hello!")

#Run the bot
app.run()
```

Stream Log :

```
2024-02-22T10:22:55.549Z ERROR - Container final17bot_0_9baf7 for site final17bot did not start within the expected time limit. Elapsed time = 247.9341095 sec

2024-02-22T10:22:55.556Z ERROR - Container final17bot_0_9baf7 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2024-02-22T10:22:55.600Z INFO  - Stopping site final17bot because it failed during startup.
```

for the steps to deploy the bot please go through the below link :

[How to deploy a Python Telegram bot on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77895365/how-to-deploy-a-python-telegram-bot-on-azure)

I successfully deployed my Telegram bot on Azure App Service, where it initially functioned correctly. However, it ceased operation after approximately 250 seconds without any discernible cause. I expected the bot to remain operational post-deployment, and although the deployment was successful, the subsequent cessation of the bot's functionality was unexpected. I conducted various troubleshooting steps, including code review, examining deployment settings, and analyzing logs, but have yet to identify the root cause of the issue. My expectation was to resolve the problem and ensure uninterrupted operation of the bot on Azure App Service.

Comment: Can you add the application setting `WEBSITES_PORT=8080` and `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800`in the App Service and check if it works?

Comment: do i need to add it in .env file too or just application setting ?

Comment: Add as Application Setting in `App Service=>Configuration`.

Comment: At first try it didnt worked stopped again at 300 something second with the below log

2024-02-22T18:04:47.872Z ERROR - Container final17bot_0_8bd06f7f for site final17bot has exited, failing site start
2024-02-22T18:04:47.879Z ERROR - Container final17bot_0_8bd06f7f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-02-22T18:04:47.884Z INFO  - Stopping site final17bot because it failed during startup.


but again after re deploying its working lets see for how much time, will update this comment later

Comment: didnt really understood what you told above Add as Application Setting in App Service=>Configuration ? 
please tell in name, value pair??

Comment: I was telling to add those two application settings `WEBSITES_PORT=8080 and WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800` under `Configuration=>General Settings` in your app service.

Comment: but in general setting there is no option to add application setting where as in application setting we have it as add new application setting, the way we added the bot token i added those two setting you told in application setting !

Comment: the bot currently worked for 30 mins straight 3rd (try) and below is the log how it stopped.

2024-02-22T19:17:04.323Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_942c77d0 for site mainbot1 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 1801.5862584 sec
2024-02-22T19:17:04.332Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_942c77d0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-02-22T19:17:04.337Z INFO  - Stopping site mainbot1 because it failed during startup.

Comment: How long is it working now?

Comment: so overall the bot is working continuous but in every 30 min - 1 hour mostly every time the container gets restarted, and it takes 3-4 mins to restart.
I've already opted for always on- on in the app configuration-general setting right after that only the bot started working for more mins which was earlier very less.

Comment: but I want is that the bot should run continuously without these container restart gap time.
 
Log :- 

2024-02-27T06:28:01.097Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_b09223 for site mainbot1 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 1802.118076 sec

2024-02-27T06:28:01.108Z ERROR - Container mainbot1_0_b09223 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2024-02-27T06:28:01.122Z INFO  - Stopping site mainbot1 because it failed during startup.